# Traefik LetsEncrypt error "too many registrations for this IP"

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, traefik, swarm

I'm pretty new in Docker and have problem with LetsEncrypt using Traefik. I have run new Docker Swarm cluster and run Traefik by following [these instructions](https://hub.docker.com/r/softonic/traefik/). But when I run Traefik service I get error:

```
proxy.1.wzx74oc2zvyo@docker-manager-3    | time="2017-11-17T13:42:51Z" level=error msg="Error creating TLS config: acme: Error 429 - urn:acme:error:rateLimited - Error creating new registration :: too many registrations for this IP" 
proxy.1.wzx74oc2zvyo@docker-manager-3    | time="2017-11-17T13:42:51Z" level=fatal msg="Error preparing server: acme: Error 429 - urn:acme:error:rateLimited - Error creating new registration :: too many registrations for this IP"
```

What cause of this error and how to fix it?

### Update

This problem not related to Traefik, when I try get cert by Certbot I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you hit the rate limit, 20 certificates per domain per week.

https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/

Update your code to avoid re-registering the same domain. This may require that you don't restart the container so often or use a volume to persist the registration in the acme.json file. See the traefik docs on setting the storage and mounting a volume for more details:

https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/

Comment: It's a new server, new cluster and first container run.

Comment: @Giwery, it doesn't matter if it's a new machine if you are running that registration for the same domain. Rate-limits are per domain.